# Canvas App ClearCollect Dataverse Filter syntax

Tags: canvas, filter, microsoft-dynamics

I have some code from an app we had built and need to repair the app and resuse part of it in another app.
Can anyone help by explaining the syntax. The code from the original app is between /* */

```
ClearCollect(
    colLinkedLevel5Terms,    
    /*
    Filter(
        'Level 5 Terms',
        'Learning Event Assessment Criteria'.'Learning Event' = [@ModelDrivenFormIntegration].Item.crd80_learningeventid
    )   
    */
    Filter(
        'Level 5 Terms',
        'Learning Event Assessment Criteria'.'Learning Event' =  [@ModelDrivenFormIntegration].Item.'Learning Event'
    )
);
```

The original use of the app was to embed it on a Dynamics form for Learning Events.
I am now trying to use the app on a different form with a field called 'Learning Event'
The error is saying either side of the = are incompatible, one is a string, the other a Guid
"Incompatible types for comparison powerapps. These types cant be compared Guid, Record"

To be honest, I dont even understand what 'Learning Event Assessment Criteria'.'Learning Event' refers to.

Answer (score 0):

crd80_learningeventid Refers to column LearningEventId. This field is manually filled or calculated but is of type string.

The name of the table itself, like the second example I.e. 'Learning Event', that refers to the GUID of the table.

Basically, one is a variable you can assign anything, the second column is a system-generated value, used to identify rows internal.